# Sql*Plus ERROR: ORA-12154 wile connecting sql*plus with oracle 12.2.0.1 Docker image

Tags: oracle, docker, sqlplus

I have pulled my oracle image from the following command.

```
docker pull store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

and run the following command to run it.

```
docker run -d -it --name <Oracle-DB> store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

that image is working fine I have tested it, then I have tried it to connect with oracle from the outside that required Oracle client to connect with So I install it, but when I run the following command.

```
sqlplus sys/Oradoc_db1@ORCLCDB as sysdba
```

to connect it with oracle It shows weird behave whit the following dialogue and error on the console.

```
  SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Aug 22 17:44:46 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name: sys
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


Enter user-name: sys
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
```

I have no clue that how to connect client outside the container.
also the I have checked the tnsname.ora file as well

```
ORCLCDB =   (DESCRIPTION =     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))     (CONNECT_DATA =       (SERVER = DEDICATED)       (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB.localdomain)     )   ) 
ORCLPDB1 =   (DESCRIPTION =     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))     (CONNECT_DATA =       (SERVER = DEDICATED)       (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLPDB1.localdomain)     )   )
```

also in some forums, I read that some missing configuration in sqlnet.ora

```
NAME.DIRECTORY_PATH= {TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT, HOSTNAME}
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 10
SSL_VERSION = 1.0
```

which is also fine.
I hope Ia not missing anything here.

Thanks, advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access to database service outside the container you will have to expose the database listener port to the host.

```
docker run -d -it -p 1521:1521 --name <Oracle-DB> store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

Best of luck!

Comment: still getting the same message on terminal.